# Apply Loop for Subprocessing Call FFMPEG in Python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, subprocess

suppose I have a audio mp3 file with length 00:04:00 (240 seconds). I want to extract parts of said file each within range 2 seconds, so it would be:

File_01 00:00:00-00:00:02, File_02 00:00:02-00:00:04, File_03 00:00:04-00:00:06 ... File_120 00:03:58-00:04:00.

I am using python, call module subprocess to run ffmpeg function. What I did, I simply put it in a loop like this:

```
count = 0
count2 = 2
count3 = 1
while count2 <= audio_length:
    ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c copy -ss %d -to %d output%d.wav' % (count, count2, count3)
    subprocess.call(ffmpeg, shell=True)
    count = count + 2
    count2 = count2 + 2
    count3 = count3 + 1
```

However, the subprocess part took a long time and it seems stucked. I've searched some insights, but i haven't found any that mentions about looping. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using an external library and working with offline audio file, [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) has builtin utility to make chunks of playable audio of given length.

Simply call `make_chunk` method from pydub.utils and provide chunk size and export playable audio chunks.

I took a 34.6 seconds long file and split in 18 chunks of 2 seconds each. Last chunk may be less than 2 seconds depending upon length which in my case was 0.6 seconds.

Working Code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

audiofile = 'example.wav'

#set chunk duration in milliseconds
chunk_duration = 2000 #2 seconds

#Convert audio to audio segment
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(audiofile)
print("audio length in seconds={}".format(len(audio_segment) / float(1000.0)))

#make chunks
chunks = make_chunks(audio_segment, chunk_duration)

end = 0
for idx,chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    start = end
    end = start + (chunk_duration//1000)
    count = idx + 1
    print("Exporting File_{}_{}:{}.wav".format(count,start,end))
    chunk.export("File_{}_{}:{}.wav".format(count,start,end))
```

Output:

```
$python splitaudio.py 
audio length in seconds=34.6
Exporting File_1_0:2.wav
Exporting File_2_2:4.wav
Exporting File_3_4:6.wav
Exporting File_4_6:8.wav
Exporting File_5_8:10.wav
Exporting File_6_10:12.wav
Exporting File_7_12:14.wav
Exporting File_8_14:16.wav
Exporting File_9_16:18.wav
Exporting File_10_18:20.wav
Exporting File_11_20:22.wav
Exporting File_12_22:24.wav
Exporting File_13_24:26.wav
Exporting File_14_26:28.wav
Exporting File_15_28:30.wav
Exporting File_16_30:32.wav
Exporting File_17_32:34.wav
Exporting File_18_34:36.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Anil_M is completely valid, but I thought it's good to mention two other ways that are fast and do not require scripting in Python (plus offer ton of extra features should you need them).

With `ffmpeg` that you have tried already:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 2 -c copy output%03d.mp3
```

And `SoX`:

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 trim 0 2 : newfile : restart
```